# What happens if there is "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN" In API's http response header? Does it cause cors error?

Tags: rest, http, cors

What is the use of this X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN?

X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN in API http response header

I am getting cors error and want to know if this is the reason for error.

And want to know how to override this header in geoserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to address your question I would describe about what are origin, the X-Frame option and Cors.

- Origin in web means the combination of the protocol like HTTP or HTTPS, domain name, port num of website. it is something like identity and it is some how unique.
- X-Frame-options is a HTTP response header that control a browser should be allowed to render a page in some html tags
  (frame, iframe, embed, or object).
  when you set to SameOrigin, it means that the page can be shown in a frame on the same origin. this response header helps to prevent clickjacking attacks.
- Cors or  Cross origin resource sharing is for when a web application tries to access resources from a different domain, and server won't send the suitable headers to allow such access.

both CORS and X-Frame-Options deal with cross-origin policies, they use in different situation and work differently.

If you're getting a CORS error it's unlikely to be directly caused by the X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN header.

I have very very few information about GeoServer but as I know You should override server configuration or server settings. If you are running GeoServer alone without something like Apache or Nginx you might need to modify its internal configuration or the servlet container it's running in like Tomcat.

Comment: You wrote: _If you're getting a CORS error it's unlikely to be directly caused by the X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN header._ But you can be more confident: it's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

No, `X-Frame-Options` controls security features related to embedding the endpoint inside an `<iframe>`.